# Selenium tests failing in Unix

Tags: maven, selenium-rc

I am trying to integrate Selenium tests in Bamboo. I am able to invoke the tests on a Windows box but when I try to replicate the same on the Unix server I get the following error:

```
*rror   29-Aug-2012 17:03:54    17:03:54.792 WARN - Caution: '/usr/bin/google-chrome': file is a script file, not a real executable.  The browser environment is no longer fully under RC control
build   29-Aug-2012 17:03:54    17:03:54.803 INFO - Launching Google Chrome...
build   29-Aug-2012 17:33:55    17:33:55.319 INFO - Killing Google Chrome...
build   29-Aug-2012 17:33:57    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   29-Aug-2012 17:33:57    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
build   29-Aug-2012 17:33:57    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   29-Aug-2012 17:33:57    [INFO] Total time: 33:21.497s
build   29-Aug-2012 17:33:57    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 29 17:33:57 BST 2012
build   29-Aug-2012 17:33:57    [INFO] Final Memory: 28M/164M
build   29-Aug-2012 17:33:57    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   29-Aug-2012 17:33:57    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:selenium-maven-plugin:2.3:selenese (test) on project iopscience-webapp: Execution test of goal org.codehaus.mojo:selenium-maven-plugin:2.3:selenese failed. SeleniumCommandTimedOutException -> [Help 1]*
```

I am using the selenium-maven-plugin to run the selenese tests suits. Following is the extract of my pom.xml

```
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.3</version>
                 <configuration>
                   <browser>*googlechrome</browser>
                   <suite>Testsuite-UI.html</suite>
                   <startURL>http://localhost:8082/</startURL>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>test</id>
                       <phase>integration-test</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>selenese</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
```

Please let me know if there is any specific configuration to be done on Linux to run the test suites?

Comment: Try with Firefox browser and see if it works.

Comment: I seem to have gone past this error with a change in the configuration. I have explicitly mentioned the path to chrome and firefox as follows <browser>*firefox /path/to/chrome</browser>

This seems to have fixed the issue. But the error that I get now is as follows:
org.codehaus.mojo:selenium-maven-plugin:2.3:selenese failed: Timed out waiting for profile to be created! -> [Help 1]